# Prestashop: Filter product attributes

Tags: prestashop

I've installed prestashop and I've created a product and created 2 products attributes:

- Brand (containing `Apple` and `Samsung`)
- Model (containing `iPhone 5`, `iPhone 5C`, `iPhone 5S`, `iPhone 56`, `Galaxy S3`, `Galaxy S4`, etcc..)

And this is how they are arranged together:

[image]

When looking at the product this shows `Brand` and `Model` as a dropdown list, which is great, but when selecting `Apple`, shows ALL of the Models, and if I select `Apple > Galaxy S3` just says "The product does not exist in this model".

Is there a way I can HIDE any non-matching Models based on their Brand?
(When selecting Apple only the one for apple should show up).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I sorted the problem with Attribute Wizard module. This module allows you to filter attributes according to the existing combination, as in the sown example.